# Blazor App Deployed on IIS Not Accessible through Public IP

Tags: c#, iis, blazor-webassembly

I am working on a project with a front-end in Blazor Wasm and a backend in Asp.Net Core. I wanted to set up a staging environment for my apps and I published both apps and deployed them on a VM in IIS. Both Apps are working fine in the VM on the local host. I opened the ports to access them outside the network. When I access them from the local IP within the network both apps are working. But when I access them outside the network using public IP, the backend works fine but the Blazor Project throws 503 Service unavailable error for all the dlls.

I have installed URL Rerouting and I have tried deleting the obj and bin folders and then publishing again but no luck.

Comment: What kind of project did you create in VS? Blazor WebAssembly with ASP.NET Core Hosted?

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Yes I have created Blazor WebAssembly with ASP.NET Core Hosted

Comment: Have you checked the IIS logs? Can you provide details about the error? Also, make sure the application pool assigned to the Blazor application is running and has the necessary permissions to access the required files.